# Display Submenu based on the selected radio button in TYPO3 TCA forms

Tags: php, typo3

I want to create dynamic TCA forms for my TYPO3 extension records form. The form should have three radio buttons and selecting any one of them should display a new select list.

```
'author' => array(
             'config' => array(
                         'type` => 'radio',
                         'foreign_table' => 'tx_MyExt_domain_model_author',
            ))
```

This will for example display: `Rob, James, Kurt`. Selecting on `Rob`, the `foreign_table_where` should be `AND where tx_MyExt_domain_model_author.author='Rob'` and should display `list` of the books written by the selected author

OR

the following is just a pseudo code, I just want to know if its a possibility in TCA forms?

```
    'books' => array(
                 'config' => array(
                             'type` => 'select',
                            'items => array(#Show list of books with Rob as author),
                                      array(#Show list of books with James as author),                                  
                                      array(#Show list of books with Kurt as author),

            ))
```

Comment: Sounds to me that you would be using a combination of JavaScript and PHP there. The JavaScript would be utilized to hide the buttons that are not supposed to appear till the buttons that are supposed to be clicked are clicked. PHP would be used to generate what text you want to show. I would need more information if you plan on getting more help with this.

Comment: What is your actual question? And: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: @Michael I re-framed the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would rather do that with FlexForms. A FlexForm is the form you see when you edit your plugin dataset in the plugin tab. Within them you can set conditions regarding the visibility of certain form fields (Your list of books) depending on othters (Your author). Here are some good explanations. With google search "typo3 flexforms condition" you will get lots of other tutorials and helpfull stuff!

http://wiki.typo3.org/Extension_Development,_using_Flexforms

http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_api/4.2.0/view/4/2/#id4256737 (see bottom)